# Processing error: x cannot be resolved or is not a field. Want to be able to click on all ellipses

Tags: java, processing

Im using processing in java mode

I want to make a simple game where ducks (currently ellipses) go across the screen using arrays and using the mouse you have to click on all the ducks to go to the next level. Im currently trying to work out being able to click on all the ellipses that appear.

My full code is:

```
Bird b;

Bird [] birds;

int score;

void setup() {
  size (800, 600);

  b = new Bird();
  score = 0;

  birds = new Bird[4];

  for (int i=0; i<birds.length; i++) {
    birds[i] = new Bird();
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(200);

  b.update();
  b.display();
  
  //show mouse cursor
  fill(255, 0, 0, 100);
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 10);
  
  for (int i=0; i<birds.length; i++) {
    birds[i].update();
    birds[i].display();
  }
  fill(255);
  textSize(48);
  textAlign(LEFT);
  text("Score: " + score, 50, 50);
  
  float distanceFromClick = dist(mouseX, mouseY, birds.x, birds.y);
  
  if(mousePressed && distanceFromClick < 25) {
   score += 1; //increases score 
  }
}
 void mousePressed() {
 }
class Bird {
  //props
  float x, y, w, h, vx, vy;
    //Constructor
    Bird() {
    x = -100;
    y = random(100, 500);
    w = 50;
    h = 50;
    vx = 2;
    vy = 0;
  }
  //methods
  void update() {
    x += random(0, 2)*vx;
    y += vy;
  }
  void display () {
    //active area
    fill(255, 255, 0, 100);
    ellipse(x, y, w, h);
  }
}
```

I want to be able to click on all the birds from the array instead of one bird but when I change b.x and b.y to birds.x and birds.y I get the error "x cannot be resolved or is not a field"

on line float `distanceFromClick = dist(mouseX, mouseY, birds.x, birds.y);`

Comment: "My full code is:" - your full code starts with a method call `size (800, 600);`. It's really *not* full code. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `Bird` has that field, but `birds` is of type `Bird[]`, and the *array* doesn't have a field called `x`. Which bird's `x` field are you actually interested in?

Comment: @JonSkeet I want to manipulate the birds created by the arrays so would I have to declare another x for that array?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that - but I expect your `dist` method takes 4 separate `float` values - what *specific* float value do you expect `birds.x` to evaluate to when `birds` is an array? (And no, you can't "declare another x for that array" - you can't declare extra fields for arrays. The array is just a collection of elements.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Standard Processing syntax was used.  Processing is a java based language: https://processing.org/reference/

Comment: @apodidae: I strongly suspect you'd still find the first version of this question was definitely *not* full code. I'm not familiar with "processing", but I'd be very surprised if `birds.x` was valid. What would it mean?

Comment: b.x is the xcoordinate of a bird created by his Bird class.

Comment: @apodidae: That's fine for `b.x`, but what about `birds.x` which is the expression causing the problem?

Comment: The code has been changed from the original post, see my addendum for a runnable demo.

Comment: @apodidae this code does work so what the next step?

Answer (score 0):

The following code should be removed from draw() and moved to mousePressed():

Move this:

```
float distanceFromClick = dist(mouseX, mouseY, birds.x, birds.y);
  
  if(mousePressed && distanceFromClick < 25) {
   score += 1; //increases score 
  }
```

To mousePressed() and add a loop to check the x,y coordinates of each bird for proximity, ie birds[i].x and birds[i].y:

```
 void mousePressed() {
    for (int i=0; i<birds.length; i++) {
    float distanceFromClick = dist(mouseX, mouseY, birds[i].x, birds[i].y );
    if (distanceFromClick < 25) {
      println(distanceFromClick);
      score += 1;
    }
  }
 }
```

It is not necessary to re-do the constructor; it will work as you have it.

Comment: How does that help with `dist(mouseX, mouseY, birds.x, birds.y)` where `birds` is of type `Bird[]`?

Comment: It gets rid of the error message so he can continue to develop the code.  Have you tried running his code?

Comment: No, I'm not about to install a whole other platform just to run the code - but I don't see that you've changed anything about the line `float distanceFromClick = dist(mouseX, mouseY, birds.x, birds.y);` - are you saying that just changing the code as per your answer, that line of code will now be okay?

Comment: @apodidae I'm sorry but I don't think I understand,  I went on to change the constructor and initialize the birds just like you did but I still get the error, do I keep `float distanceFromClick = dist(mouseX, mouseY, birds.x, birds.y);`  like it is?

Comment: No, it has to be placed inside a loop in mousePressed(); see edited answer.  The constructor may be used the way you initially posted it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing this error message, the first step is to carefully review your code and check for any typos or syntax errors. It's also a good idea to double-check that you have all of the necessary libraries installed and that your configuration settings are correct.
learn more - https://hinditechbate.blogspot.com/2023/04/what-does-processing-error-x-cannot-be.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).